# Program terminates when reading data from excel in selenium web driver

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver

I am matching console output value with excel data. And in excel try to putting "TRUE" or "FALSE" if match found. My program is given below :

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);


    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\book.xls");

    FileOutputStream webdata = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\book.xls");


    int count=0;

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
    HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");
    HSSFRow row = sh.getRow(count);
    String data = row.getCell(1).toString();
    System.out.println(data);



    if(title==data)

    {

        row.createCell(10).setCellValue("TRUE");
        wb.write(webdata);

    }
    else
    {

        row.createCell(10).setCellValue("FALSE");
        wb.write(webdata);

    }


    wb.close();
    input.close();
    driver.close();
```

**When program reach here : HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input); It terminates. I have debug it but not getting solution. can anyone help please?**

**I am getting below error in console :**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to read entire header; 0 bytes read;       expected 512 bytes
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.alertShortRead(HeaderBlock.java:227)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.readFirst512(HeaderBlock.java:208)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:128)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:361)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:342)
at mhover.main(mhover.java:52)
```

Comment: What Error/Exception are you getting ?

Comment: I have just added error list by update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue it solved now. Problem was like :

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\book.xls");
FileOutputStream webdata = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\book.xls");
```

Above code was overwriting my excel file data and was making excel blank.  So I moved code : **FileOutputStream webdata = new FileOutputStream ("D:\book.xls");** once data reading process complete. so its working now.

**New & Working code :**

```
     //CODE TO REMOVE UNNECESSARY WARNING
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");


    //CALL FIREFOX DRIVER TO OPEN IT
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);



    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\sel.xls");

    int count=0;

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
    HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");
    HSSFRow row = sh.getRow(count);
    String data = row.getCell(1).toString();
    System.out.println(data);


    FileOutputStream webdata = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\sel.xls");

    if(title.equals(data))

    {

        row.createCell(10).setCellValue("TRUE");
        wb.write(webdata);

    }
    else
    {

        row.createCell(11).setCellValue("FALSE");
        wb.write(webdata);

    }

    driver.close(); 
    wb.close();
    input.close();


}


}
```

Comment: I was also stuck in here. Can you please add the complete code in your answer ? It will be helpful for me too. Thanks.